# Solr range not filtering

Tags: java, solr, lucene

I am trying to use [price.facet.range](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#facet.range), but it doesn't work, it always returns unfiltered results

indexing:

```
<field name="price" type="sdouble" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" /> 

solrDoc.addField("price", 22.99);
```

creating query:

```
query.addNumericRangeFacet("price", 0.0 ,100.0, 0.01);
```

created query:

```
q=mobile+phone&
fl=productId+score&
payload=true&
payload.fl=full_text&
facet.range=price&
f.price.facet.range.start=0.0&
f.price.facet.range.end=100.0&
f.price.facet.range.gap=0.01&
facet=true&
/...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution

`query.addFilterQuery("price:[0 100]");`

Comment: Right.  You misunderstood the faceting feature as something that would filter the results, but it is separate.  Filter queries and faceting go hand in hand to implement "faceted navigation".    I am new to stack overflow, but if it has a feature to flag this question as "invalid" then I think that is appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for this solution Sergey. I was looking exactly for this same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Faceting always operates on filtered results ('fq' & 'q' params), unless you explicitly exclude a filter query which you didn't.  Can you reproduce the problem with the exampledocs data in Solr, or with a setup that is easy for another person to verify?

Comment: I send him one filter value q=mobile+phone, and want to filter price range, do you know how to use facet.range? What do you mean by "exampledocs data", my solr added data?